# Rails: Partial Rendering fails with ActiveModel-Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, orientdb, activemodel

I am setting up a rails5 project using OrientDB as Database (ActiveOrient, https://github.com/topofocus/active-orient)

I have two Models "Basiswert" and "Aktie", both provide a method "to_partial_path" and "to_parm" and should be qualified for partial-rendering

```
fast =  Basiswert.like 'fast*'
fast.first.to_partial_path
 => "basiswerte/basiswert"
fast.first.aktie.to_partial_path
=> "aktien/aktie"
```

Unfortunately

```
<%= render @basiswert.aktie if @basiswert.aktie.present? %>
```

fails with the following error

```
ActionView::Template::Error ('["id", 134]' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.)
```

Any suggestion where to look to solve this issue?

EDIT:

Further Investigation reveals that it's possible to render collections, 
i.e

```
<%= render [@basiswert.aktie] %>
```

renders the view correctly. Rendering the plain Object still fails with the error-message shown above.

Comment: shouldn't you be rendering `<%= render @basiswert.aktie.to_partial_path %>`

Comment: it looks like you have a plain array instead of an activemodel like object. please put a debugger into your paritial and have a look at what exactly `aktie` is. if you need more debugging tips, please have a look at this article http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: Could you please show the actual code for the controller method which is failing and the model code for Basiswert `basiswert.rb`?

Comment: The fact, that collections are rendered correctly suggest that the Rails.PartialRenderer itself causes the error, if a ActiveModel-Object is used. 
I suspect that other ActiveMode-Implementations do show a similar behavior.